# If statement with String comparison fails

Tags: java, multithreading, if-statement, string-comparison

I really don't know why the if statement below is not executing:

```
if (s == "/quit")
{
    System.out.println("quitted");
}
```

Below is the whole class.

It is probably a really stupid logic problem but I have been pulling my hair out over here not being able to figure this out.

Thanks for looking :)

```
class TextParser extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            for(int i = 0; i < connectionList.size(); i++) {
                try {               
                    System.out.println("reading " + i);
                    Connection c = connectionList.elementAt(i); 
                    Thread.sleep(200);

                    System.out.println("reading " + i);

                    String s = "";

                    if (c.in.ready() == true) {
                        s = c.in.readLine();
                        //System.out.println(i + "> "+ s);

                        if (s == "/quit") {
                            System.out.println("quitted");
                        }

                        if(! s.equals("")) {
                            for(int j = 0; j < connectionList.size(); j++) {
                                Connection c2 = connectionList.elementAt(j);
                                c2.out.println(s);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println("reading error");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Too bad we can't give +1 for edits.

Comment: == means; is this the same object. It doesn't match objects which contain the same data.

Comment: how come it's tagged 'multithreading'?

Answer (score 104):

In your example you are comparing the string objects, not their content.

Your comparison should be :

```
if (s.equals("/quit"))
```

Or if `s` string nullity doesn't mind / or you really don't like NPEs:

```
if ("/quit".equals(s))
```

Comment: I prefer s.equals("/quit"). It is cosmetically but I want to have the important current data (s) to be visible easily.

Comment: s.equales("/quit") will throw a NullPointerException is s is null, "/quit".equals(s) will never throw an NPE

Comment: So "/quit".equals(s) will mask bugs where s is unintentionally null.

Comment: @starblue good point, always something else to consider

Comment: Well, another reason to have it s.equals()... might depend on the code, but the NPE is one reason to keep the current context upfront.

Comment: @ReneS whatever string/context s is I'd still do "<data>".equals(s) for I know <data> won't be NULL whereas s might. But if s.equals(s2) then you are right, but then again you'll have to surround it with if(s!= null){ block.

Answer (score 39):

To compare Strings for equality, **don't use ==**. The **==** operator checks to see if two objects are exactly the same object:

In **Java** there are many string comparisons.

```
String s = "something", t = "maybe something else";
if (s == t)      // Legal, but usually WRONG.
if (s.equals(t)) // RIGHT
if (s > t)    // ILLEGAL
if (s.compareTo(t) > 0) // also CORRECT>
```

Comment: Checks to see that the references are the same.

Answer (score 12):

`String`s in java are objects, so when comparing with `==`, you are comparing references, rather than values. The correct way is to use `equals()`.

However, there is a way. If you want to compare `String` objects using the `==` operator, you can make use of the way the JVM copes with strings. For example:

```
String a = "aaa";
String b = "aaa";
boolean b = a == b;
```

`b` would be `true`. Why?

Because the JVM has a table of `String` constants. So whenever you use string literals (quotes `"`), the virtual machine returns *the same* objects, and therefore `==` returns `true`.

You can use the same "table" even with non-literal strings by using the [`intern()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29) method. It returns the object that corresponds to the current string value from that table (or puts it there, if it is not). So:

```
String a = new String("aa");
String b = new String("aa");
boolean check1 = a == b; // false
boolean check1 = a.intern() == b.intern(); // true
```

> It follows that for any two strings s and t, s.intern() == t.intern() is true  if and only if s.equals(t) is true.

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't do string comparisons with ==.  That operator will only check to see if it is the same instance, not the same value.  Use the .equals method to check for the same value.

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
if("/quit".equals(s))
   ...
```

or

```
if("/quit".compareTo(s) == 0) 
    ...
```

The latter makes a [lexicographic](http://www.inf.unibz.it/~calvanese/teaching/04-05-ip/lecture-notes/uni05/node19.html) comparison, and will return 0 if the two strings are the same.

Answer (score 5):

If you code in C++ as well as Java, it is better to remember that in C++, the string class has the == operator overloaded. But not so in Java. you need to use `equals()` or `equalsIgnoreCase()` for that.