# String comparison solutions in java not working

Tags: java, string

I know this question has been asked to death but I have tried all solutions that were given to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658953/if-statement-with-string-comparison-fails) and my if statement still doesn't execute..
My code goes like this:

```
String s = "Something*like*this*";
String[] sarray = s.split("\\*");

for(int i = 0; i < sarray.length; i++) {
  if(sarray[i].equals("this")) {
    //do something
  }
}
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't see any problems with this code. Try printing out the elements of the array in your loop. Also check for spurious whitespace characters.

Comment: Maybe your input string is not *exactly* the one you use in this sample. Consider there are characters that are not printable (so you don't usually see them neither in your editor, nor in the console)

Comment: Your posted code works fine for me. Post the actual SSCCE you used to test the code.

Comment: It works as expected. What is your environment? java version etc. Are you using threading ?

Comment: I'm using eclipse. The problem was with the way I store and retrieve s from permanent storage on the android device. I changed to sql database and it all works. Thanks for your comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works as expected indeed

```
for (String token : "Something*like*this*".split("\\*")) {
    if (token.equals("this")) {
        System.out.println("Found this");
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, unfortunately it hasn't worked and by messing around with your solution, I've concluded that there is a problem with where I get my "Something*like*this" from (I don't create it) even though it looks fine when outputted. I think restructuring that will solve my problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The `if`  *will* execute here.

Test this in drJava interactions pane(or your fav IDE pane), the individual pieces(to check they each work).

```
Welcome to DrJava.  Working directory is C:\JavaProjects
> String s = "Something*like*this";

> String[] sarray = s.split("\\*");

> sarray[0]

"Something"

> sarray[1]

"like"

> sarray[2]

"this"

> sarray[3]

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

> sarray.length

> 3 

> sarray[1].equals("this")

false
>
```